# Spyder keyboard shortcut binding Shift+Return and Shift-Enter to same function

Tags: spyder

I can bind Shift-Return (the key near the letters/backspace button) to a certain command. However, Spyder seems to recognize Shift-Enter (the key near the 10-key) as a different command.

I expected these two to be synonymous, but Spyder recognizes them as 2 unique key combinations. How can I bind both these key combinations to a single function on the keyboard shortcuts?

I am on Spyder 5.4.3